# Msg's with extra variables in elm inputs

Tags: elm

I am trying to partition my `Msg` values in Elm (0.18) into different types.  I'd like it to conform to this kind of typing:

```
type MsgSession
    = LogIn
    | LogOut


type MsgSettings
    = SetUsername String
    = SetPassword String

type Msg
    = SessionMsg MsgSession
    | SettingsMsg MsgSettings
    ...
```

My update function looks like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SessionMsg sessionMsg ->
            sessionUpdate sessionMsg model

        SettingsMsg settingsMsg ->
            settingsUpdate settingsMsg model
        ...
```

...which means that I have to define the child updates as well...

```
sessionUpdate : MsgSession -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
sessionUpdate msg model =
    case msg of
        LogIn ->
            -- do stuff
        LogOut ->
            -- do stuff
```

My LogOut event looks like this, and works fine:

```
button [onClick (SessionMsg LogOut)] [text "Log Out"]
```

But once there is a variable involved with the event, it doesn't work.  I have a similar setup for `settingsUpdate`:

```
settingsUpdate : MsgSettings -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
settingsUpdate msg model =
    case msg of
        SetUsername string ->
           ...
        SetPassword string ->
           ...
```

But I can't get `onInput` to send as a variable. For example, this code

```
input [onInput SettingsMsg SetUsername] []
```

Yields this error:

```
Function `onInput` is expecting 1 argument, but was given 2.
483|                                   onInput SettingsMsg SetUsername
```

Parentheses also don't work.

```
input [onInput (SettingsMsg SetUsername)] []
```

yields

```
The argument to function `SettingsMsg` is causing a mismatch.
483|                                            SettingsMsg SetUsername)
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `SettingsMsg` is expecting the argument to be:
    MsgSettings
But it is:
    String -> MsgSettings
```

What do I have to pass into `onInput` to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use composition:

```elm
input [onInput (SettingsMsg << SetUsername)] []
```

Which, if you're more comfortable with explicit lambdas, looks like this:

```elm
input [onInput (\name -> SettingsMsg (SetUsername name))] []
```